# What if the client ignore the SYN and SYN/ACK from the server but send the ACK directly?

Tags: tcp, tcpdf, tcplistener

If the client ignore the SYN and SYN/ACK from the server but send the ACK directly, How will the server respond？

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The ACK must contain the sequence number from the peer which gets ACKed. And to get this sequence number the packet from the peer must be known, i.e. cannot be ignored. If an unexpected (non-matching) sequence number gets used the packet gets discarded by the peer or a RST is issued.